# Find expected value of discrete trials same probability.

Tags: probability, statistics, expectation

I am struggling with a question. I have found the probability of success to be $\frac{k!}{k^k}$. How do I find the expected number of trials before a success? For example, this is similar to if I rolled a dice with a probability of $\frac{1}{6}$ what is the expected number of trials I would have to take to get lets say the side 2? Thanks

Comment: Say, we are at the $i^{th}$ experiment. Is $k=i$? Or $k$ does not have anything to do with $i$.

Comment: Is $k$ fixed or the probability of success in the k-th trial is equal to $k!/k^k$?

Comment: k is fixed. there are an infinite number of trials with a finite probability of each trial. The only way I can seem to find E(x) is if I have a finite number of trials but there must be an expected value of the number of trials needed to gain a success, with my dice example, the expected number of throws of the dice to get a 2 where each throw is $\frac{1}{6}$ probability.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say that $p$ is the probability of success and that $X$ denotes the number of failures that precede the first success. If $S$ is the event that the first trial is a success, and $F$ the event that it is a failure then:

$\mathbb{E}X=\mathbb{E}\left(X\mid S\right)P\left(S\right)+\mathbb{E}\left(X\mid F\right)P\left(F\right)=0.p+\left(1+\mathbb{E}X\right)\left(1-p\right)=\left(1+\mathbb{E}X\right)\left(1-p\right)$

This equation enables you to find $\mathbb EX$.

Essential is here that $\mathbb{E}\left(X\mid F\right)=1+\mathbb{E}X$.

After the failure the process "starts over" with $1$ failure in our pocket.

Comment: interesting, so the expected value $E(x) = \frac{1-p}{p}$?

Comment: Yes. Also see [geometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution). Especially the one counting failures.